# Why the Text inside my tabbed activity did not show up?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I tried to create Tabbed Activity Manually. Inside my preview XML it show the text like the picture below.
[image]

But when i run the apps on my phone it did not shows the text. I wonder why?
Can someone enlighten me which part did I do wrong?

I follow the code and tried to do it with my own because the new fragment provided by android is hard to understand so I decided to do it manually by following the tutorial but as I run the apps through my phone I discover that the text did not show up. I guess I'm missing something here which I don't quite sure which step did I miss. I would be very grateful if somebody can help enlighten me about this matter inside my xml layout page.

[image]

Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PAID"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="UNPAID"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ITEM POSTED"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager =  findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }

    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            Fragment fragment=null;

            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    fragment= new Paid();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment= new Unpaid();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment= new ItemPosted();
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;



        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }



}
```

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ItemPosted"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Unpaid" />
        <activity android:name=".Paid" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not using initialize tabs in xml bu you can use this way to implement tabs in your activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


      <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

and in your pager adapter you can assign names of tabs

```
  public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
   private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
   }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

 }
```

in your activity you can add this line

```
   SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new 
    SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager =  findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager)
   mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFrag(new Paid(),"Paid");
   mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFrag(new Unpaid(),"Unpaid");
   mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFrag(new ItemPosted(),"ItemPosted");
```

Comment: Why you repeat same answer after 19 hours when there is a accepted answer ?

Comment: i don't repeat your answer , i prepare answer but not submit

Comment: Besides this, your answer is not complete. It seems to me that both account belong to same person, ins't it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set title from `SectionsPagerAdapter` by implementing `getPageTitle` like below:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ....

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = "";

        switch(position){
            case 0:
                title = "PAID";
                break;
            case 1:
                title = "UNPAID";
                break;
            case 2:
                title = "ITEM POSTED";
                break;
        }

        return title;
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: @lastgg, what is the problem of my answer? why you revert accepted answer after 19 hours? Is there any problem? please correct me